# Why does an HTTP request to google images return the image as gstatic

Tags: httprequest

I'm trying to send an HTTP request to

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=cats&tbm=isch&ie=UTF-8&safe=active
```

to get the image URL of the first image.

However, I receive URL like:

```
https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR1M6cnFrSeLZ4Mhu6G7M4_1hxuM1Svg-QJ2dnBYv5kM1Kg5GDzx91AZccX-Q&s
```

instead of the URL that I find when I search it manually (https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png).

Any ideas? The problem is that in the HTML the URL is different.

Answer (score 0):

I believe gstatic is google's domain for serving static content.

I would bet that the image inside the DOM of google's search results page is actually being served from their own static content domain (gstatic) rather than the actual website that is hosting the original image (icatcare.org).